# playframework Input helper extra parameter with - character

Tags: templates, playframework-2.0

I would like to pass extra parameter to input field which contains "-" character,

```
@helper.inputText(
       shopintForm("name"),
       '_label ->  Messages.get("spmanage.page.field.name"),
       'class ->  "form-control",
       'id -> "iname",
        'data-msg-required -> Messages.get("form.data.requires")
   )
```

but compiler gives error:

> Error: value - is not a member of Symbol

Either extra parameter with - are not permitted or I am doing something wrong here :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@helper.inputText(
       shopintForm("name"),
       '_label ->  Messages.get("spmanage.page.field.name"),
       'class ->  "form-control",
       'id -> "iname",
       Symbol("data-msg-required") -> Messages.get("form.data.requires")
   )
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It worked. In between i found that it is bug which is going to be fixed in 2.3 https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2061

Answer (score 0):

Wasted so much time after getting struck because of the same issue. After finally figuring out that its a bug in play 2.2.x version, tried in the following way.

```
Symbol("data-msg-required") -> Messages.get("form.data.requires")
```

This worked like a charm!